# How to show image of tif coordinates obtained from Tessnet (Tesseract)

Tags: c#, ocr, tiff, tesseract

I'm running OCR on the tesseract engine with Tessnet as a C# wrapper. I have obtained image coordinates of the recognized words and I would like to use those coordinates to show only that part of the page. I don't care if this page portion is saved as a separate image or if it just highlights the section of the tif image somehow.

Here is my current code:

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"U:\user files\bwalker\ocrTesting.txt");
            Bitmap image = new Bitmap(@"u:\user files\bwalker\2849257.tif");
            tessnet2.Tesseract ocr = new tessnet2.Tesseract();
            ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.,$-/#&=()\"':?"); // If digit only
            ocr.Init(@"C:\Users\bwalker\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\tessnetWinForms\tessnetWinForms\bin\Release\", "eng", false); // To use correct tessdata
            List<tessnet2.Word> result = ocr.DoOCR(image, System.Drawing.Rectangle.Empty);
            string Results = "";
            foreach (tessnet2.Word word in result)
            {
                Results += word.Confidence + ", " + word.Text + ", " +word.Top+", "+word.Bottom+", "+word.Left+", "+word.Right+"\n";
            } 
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"U:\user files\bwalker\ocrTesting2.txt", true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(Results);
                writer.Close();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Completed");
```

And here's a section of the resulting .txt file:

```
14, Due, 105, 136, 1886, 1962
89, Date, 105, 136, 1978, 2064
50, 06/16/2009, 105, 136, 2298, 2504
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this. After getting the coordinates for the words, I am doing this to display the associated images:

```
System.Drawing.Rectangle dueDateRectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(dueDateRect1, dueDateRect2, dueDateRect4 - dueDateRect1, dueDateRect3 - dueDateRect2);
System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat format = image.PixelFormat;
Bitmap cloneBitmap = image.Clone(dueDateRectangle, format);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
cloneBitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
ms.Position = 0;
BitmapImage dueDateImage = new BitmapImage();
dueDateImage.BeginInit();
dueDateImage.StreamSource = ms;
dueDateImage.EndInit();
dueDateImageBox.Source = dueDateImage;
```